# RealmSwift: Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I'm trying to query for the token and user_id from my realm database and then pass to my private var token and userId but I keep getting thrown this error

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

at `return particular.id` and

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Int!'

at `_userId = getId()`

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Users {
  private var _userId: Int!
  private var _token: String!

var userId: Int {
    _userId = getId()
    return _userId
}

func getId () {

    guard let userName = Data.sharedInstance.userName  else { print("Empty username"); return }

    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        if let particular = realm.objects(Particulars).filter("username == '\(userName)'").first {
            return particular.id
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // handle error
        print(error)
    }

}
}
```

So there are two things that I want to know:

- Why am I being thrown this error?
- Is there a better way of doing so? (I.e. more efficient way of querying)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined as `func getId ()` which means it doesn't return a value. Then you try and return something at `return particular.id`. You need to change your function definition to `func getId() -> Int?` and then also add a `return nil` as the last line for when your fetch fails (same for your `guard` statement).

Of course, you'll also have to handle that `nil` value when calling `getId()` in the `var userId`, or change `userId` to be optional as well.